# PowerShell - Delete files based on "LastAccessTime"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a command that is supposed to delete anything with the "LastAccessTime" older than 30 days. However, when I run it, it just modifies the LastAccessTime and doesn't delete. Command is below.

Get-ChildItem '\servername\share\folder in the share' | ?{$*.LastAccessTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | ?{!$*.psiscontainer} | Remove-Item

The account I'm running this as has access to the share, including delete access (tested this manually). If I take out **| Remove-Item** and change the days to be older than 1 day, it returns the files. Should I use something other than **Remove-Item**?

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid using aliases in your script here on serverfault, as they decrease the readability of scripts.

Apart from that, your missing some underscores, I'm guessing your script should read:

```
Get-ChildItem '\servername\share\folder in the share' | where {$_.LastAccessTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | where {!$_.psiscontainer} | Remove-Item
```